# How to match two array and keep the matched value into a new array using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Dear all,
How i match 2 array and keep the matched value into a new array using c#?

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayA.Length; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < arrayB.Length; k++)
    {
        if (arrayA[j] == arrayB[k])
        {               
            arrayB[k];
         //How i keep this matched record into a new array?
        }
    }
}
```

**Another thing:** Is their any short cut way to match 2 array and keep the record into a new array?
Any kind heart. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't use LINQ:

```
var matchingValues = arrayA.Intersect(arrayB).ToArray();
```

SIDE NOTE:
the resulting array will have distinct values.

Comment: I don't believe this'll match on the values at a particular index, it'll just return values that are in both arrays.

Comment: @Massif: Yes, but actually the OP's code compares any value in the first array with any value in the second one, not only the value at the same index. So I suppose is trying to implement an intersection...

Comment: good point... I must learn to re-activate brain before commenting.

Answer (score 5):

Store it in a `List<int>` or any type you have. (I assume yours is int)

```
   List<int> list = new List<int>();
   for (int j = 0; j < arrayA.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < arrayB.Length; k++)
            {
                if (arrayA[j] == arrayB[k])
                {               
                    list.Add(arrayB[k]); // HERE !!

                }
            }
        }
```

Now if you need to change it to an array, you can do at the end:

```
 int[] finalArray = list.ToArray();
```